# A good way to validate Items in a List Scala

Tags: scala, list, validation

Hi i have a question regarding validating a List in Scala. I have a method that looks somewhat like this:

```
def validate(item: Item): Try[Unit] = {
   if (item.isValid) Success(())
   else Failure(new isNotValidException("not valid"))
}
```

Now i am using this method to validate a `itemList: List[Item]` as follow:

```
def listIsValid(list: List[Item]): Try[Unit] = {
  list
    .map(validate(_))
    .collectFirst{ case f @ Failure(_: Exception) => f }
    .getOrElse(Success(()))
}
```

Which i ultimately want to resolve to a single `Try[Unit]` (either Success if all items are valid, or a Failure if at least one item is not valid.

Is this a good way to validate all items in a List? Or is there a better way to validate items in lists? It should fail fast and if one item fails i don't need to know if other items are invalid at the time. The list validation is used in a for comprehension and ultimately needs to resolve to a single `Try[Unit]` again

Comment: how about something like `list.map(validate(_)).forall(_.isSuccess)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i would use the method `exists` on Lists, and write this method as follows :

```
def listIsValid(list: List[Item]): Boolean = {
        list.exists(!_.isValid)
  }
```

Comment: Looks promising if you want to turn the boolean in a Try[unit] again. Would you recommend  passing this boolean to another method, for instance: `def doValidate(valid: Boolean):Try[Unit] = { if (valid) Success(()) else Failure() ` ? Or is there a clean inline way to do it?

Comment: you can add if statement  : 
```if (list.exists(!_.isValid)) Failure(..)
else Success(())```
but i have to say that this implementation is a little bit confusing, we are trying to know if the list contains any invalid item, this does not match our return type which is `Try[Unit]`

Comment: The sense of the function is wrong in that it returns `true` if there's an item in the list that isn't valid, when it ought to return `false` in that case and `true` only if all items are valid. Consequently, you might prefer: `list.forall(_.isValid)` instead of `list.exists(!_.isValid)`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to check if every element in a sequence fulfills a predicate you use `forall`:

```
list.forall(_.isValid)
```

For more details check the [forall documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#forall(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean)